# Uniformly bounded variation and convergence

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Suppose $\{f_n\}_{n\geq1}$ is a series of bounded variation functions on $[a,b]$ satisfying:
$$ T_a^b(f_n)\leq M_1, | f_n(a) |\leq M_2 $$
for all $n$, where $M_1, M_2$ are real numbers.

I'm wondering: if $f_n$ converges to a function $f$ everywhere, does it imply

$$ T_a^b(f_n) \rightarrow T_a^b(f)$$

If it doesn't hold, can we make a few justifications?

It just occurred to me when I'm studying real analysis. Although it seems intuitive, I can't directly think of a proof or give a counterexample.

Thanks!

Comment: What's $T_a^b$? The total variation?

Comment: $f_{n}=1_{[n,n+1]}$ is a counterexample i think

Comment: @Basti nice. I was just thinking about zigzagging functions but your example surely outshines mine.

Comment: Somewhat [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/126625).

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, assume that $a=0$ and $b=1$. We define $f_n$ as the indicator function of the interval $(0,1/n)$. In this way,

- $T_0^1\left(f_n\right)=2$ (reached with the subdivision $\{0,1/(2n),1\}$ and no other subdivision can do better),
- $f_n(0)=0$ for all $n$ and
- $f_n(x)\to 0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

However, under pointwise convergence, [it is true that $T_a^b(f)\leqslant \liminf_{n\to \infty} T_a^b (f_n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126625/pointwise-convergent-and-total-variation?noredirect=1&lq=1).